# CPU Overload on DSP.SE

Tags: discussion, support

Lately, my browser has been causing my CPU (quad core, all of them) to go nearly 100% when opening pages on this site.

Granted I have an older computer, but still.  Other sites to this as well, with the added "bonus" of downloading advertising videos when I am on a limited data connection.  That't not welcome.

Here, at least the download doesn't go crazy, the new animated crap (or whatever it is that it does) runs my CPU too hard.  I've got everything shutoff that I possibly can in my browser settings to stop this kind of stuff, short of disabling javascript.

Annoying bordering on prohibitive.

Comment: That really sucks. Have you tried inspecting which elements/scripts take the most of CPU? Does it also happen in different browsers? 
Personally I am always behind AdGuard and Pi-hole :)

Comment: @jojek Now you've got me wanting to install PiHole....  I haven't seen this myself, Cedron, but will look out for it. I'm playing with some older machines at the moment.

Comment: @jojek I have not.  Minimizing the window, letting it settle, and then popping it up again seems to be working.  I have an Intel i3 Four core at 2.4 GHz each running Linux and a Firefox Broswer.  The browsers I have tend not to do so well on a lot of sites so I don't generally use them.  I remember there was a discussion a bit back about allowing animated ads on the site.  I am making an assumption they may be responsible.  I think I liked the internet better before it went so commercial.  (double meaning intended)  Thanks.

Comment: @PeterK.  I'd be curious on what you find out.  I don't feel like spending any time pursuing this.  Specs Mint 17, Firefox 66.

Comment: I tested with Mint 19.3, Firefox 66.0 and there were no problems. Maybe upgrade the browser or quickly test with a fresh install in your home dir, `wget https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/66.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-66.0.tar.bz2 -O - |tar -xj` then `cd firefox` and `./firefox`.

Comment: @OlliNiemitalo Thanks Olli, my machines are old.  I actually use my RaspberryPI with Chromium to access my bank account (I don't connect it to the internet for any other purpose other than software installs).  There's something about pouring new wine into an old wineskin that makes me hesitant to uprgrade.  MIdori 0.4.3 actually blows up.  Well, disappears is more accurate when I open more than one DSP.SE tab.  Qupzilla works but it doesn't look as good and I haven't tested it extensively.

Comment: Does the problem persist? I've never noticed a slowdown in this site, except when editing long Latex based formulas in an answer. I'm accessing the site with a Celeron 2.0 GHz double core device and Latest Firefox with AdBlock. No it's running fine. Only multiple Youtube and Facebook pages can push the harddisk to %100 due some *<!*#$ windows paging mechanisms...

Comment: @Fat32 Yeah it persists.  It occurs on any stackexchange site, like when I am following links on searches.  What's worse is that if gobbles up memory, forcing swapping, which slows my computer down to molasses speed.  The only recourse is to reboot.